Generate curves to connect instances in 3D space

Hi everyone. The empties are created as instances, and what I need is to create individual straight curves using them as start/end points (the blue lines represent what I want to achieve). The thing is that I tried using the indexes of the instances to do it, but sometimes they are not organized as I would like (ideally, from bottom to top). Sometimes, for example, the top one has index 0 and the bottom one index 1, and it’s pretty random. How can I control it? And also, how can I generate this "array" of curves without making them individually? Because this is supposed to be variable in height, so maybe I will have 3 empties or 5.


Here for example is correct but if i change the seed this could happened:

Because indexes goes completely unpredictable, not by position


Pretty straightforward. Just use a Sort Elements node with the Z position as the sort sort weight. Then sample that index and set the position of each correlated index in the mesh line to set it's position.

The number of segments is taken from the size of the instance collection so it will dynamically update to match.

